# Showing that the Lebesgue integral of a function converges to the measure of a set.

Tags: analysis

Let $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space. I am trying to show that if $f$ is is $\mu$-summable and $\mu$ is finite (i.e. $\mu(X)<\infty$) then

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_X |f|^{1/n} d\mu = \mu(\{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\}).$$

I think I am mean to apply the Lebesgue dominating convergence theorem but I am not sure how to begin. I was thinking maybe taking the dominated function to be $\max\{|f|,1\}$. But I am not sure if $|f|^{1/n}$ is measurable for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

How should I proceed in showing the equation is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $\varphi(t) := \sqrt[n]{t}$ is continuous in $[0,+\infty)$, so the composition $\varphi\circ |f|$ is measurable for every measurable function $f$.

The pointwise limit of the sequence $|f|^{1/n}$ is
$$
g(x) := \begin{cases}
0, &\text{if}\ f(x) = 0,\\
1, &\text{if}\ f(x) \neq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Since $t^{1/n}\leq t$ for every $t\geq 1$, we have that $|f|^{1/n} \leq \max\{|f|, 1\}$.
We can then pass to the limit in the integral using the Dominated Convergence Theorem, obtaining
$$
\lim_n \int_X |f|^{1/n}\, d\mu = \int_X g \, d\mu = \mu\{x\in X:\ f(x) \neq 0\}.
$$

Comment: How to proceed from there?

Comment: Your question was: is $|f|^{1/n}$ measurable? The answer is: yes, it is.

Comment: Ok, I just realized that Dman $\neq$ user448133.

Comment: Whoops, sorry my friend had logged onto his account on my laptop